# USB device for Samsung Intercept not recognized from <sdk>/tools/adb devices

Tags: android, usb, adb

I created an Android App in Eclipse that I'd like to test on my Samsung Intercept phone.

I downloaded the Windows ADB USB driver from Google and added the following lines to the android_winusb.inf based on the values found in Device Manager for my Samsung Intercept phone (based on other posts in this forum):

```
;SAMSUNG_Android  
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_681C  
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_681C&MI_01
;
```

(FYI the Device Manager Ids are:

```
USB\VID_04E8&PID_681C&REV_0224  
USB\VID_04E8&PID_681C)
```

After putting the Samsung phone in USB Debug mode, the drivers installed 'fine'... I'm seeing a new entry ("Android ADB Interface") in Device Manager under "Android Phone".

However, when I run `<sdk>/tools/adb devices`, the phone is not showing up as an available device (the list is empty).

I tried ending the adb process in Task Manager, but this was not successful.

Is there anything else that I'm missing?

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, installed Eclipse and Android SDK in the program files X86 folder.

Comment: Have you rebooted since doing this?  If not, can't hurt to try.

Comment: No luck so far connecting my phone to adb... so can not test my custom app on the phone before creating a final package.  So... after testing with the emulator, went ahead and created the final install package (.apk) for my new app, copied the .apk file to a folder on the phone, browsed to the folder using "My Files", clicked on the application and it installed.  I'm happy that the program is working... but I'm sure that there are 'tweaks' that need to be made based how it behaves on the phone... It is a longer process, but manageable.

Comment: Download and install the stuff Samsung has for their phones on their website, there is a working ADB driver included.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.knowyourcell.com/samsung/samsung-intercept/intercept-guides/534403/how_to_take_screenshots_on_the_samsung_intercept.html) seems to have instructions for setting up that phone with the SDK, and for taking screenshots as well. **Note: I have not tested these instructions as I do not own that phone.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the phone in a Linux VM. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) [is free for personal, evaluation, and educational use](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL). Any modern Linux distro should support almost any android phone out of the box, provided the SDK is installed of course. If you are new to Linux, try out [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download). I'm partial to [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) myself. Just attach the phone to the VM from the USB devices menu. It's not the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: In (K)Ubuntu you need to add a udev rule to get it to recognize the phone.

Comment: Can you elaborate, or provide a link that shows how to accomplish this?